# Why was the __pycache__ directory not made hidden?

Tags: python, bytecode

This is a question that I believe must have been asked often, but which I have been unable to find or find an answer to

When compiling/executing python, a `__pycache__` directory is created, mostly containing bytecodes to gain time the next time the code in that module is used.

> note that this can be suppressed

My question is why was the `__pycache__` directory made hidden when the language was designed?
(for example `.__pycache__` on unix systems)

This is possible and doable as the git program does it with the `.git` folder, which I believe is also hidden on windows machines

Comment: I'm just guessing, but perhaps it is because treating filenames that begin with a period as "hidden" is just a unix convention; it is not standard across all operating systems.  Also, some operating systems do not even allow filenames that begin with a period.

Comment: @JohnGordon you could both start the name with a dot, and make the folder hidden on Windows systems, like the .git folder in git repositories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The PEP itself mentions this as a rejected proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#pyc):

> ## .pyc
>
> A proposal was floated to call the `__pycache__` directory `.pyc` or some other dot-file name. This would have the effect on *nix systems of hiding the directory. There are many reasons why this was rejected by the BDFL [[20]](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-dev@python.org/msg45203.html) including the fact that dot-files are only special on some platforms, and we actually do not want to hide these completely from users.

Basically, they wanted to reduce the clutter in the source code directory, but they weren't trying to hide implementation, just compartmentalize it better.

Comment: So would it have some effect on the bytecode if we hid those __pycache__ folders ourself on a unix system by doing .__pycache__?

Comment: Ok apparently hiding those folders manually just ends up in python not reading them and then it creates a new pycache folder anyway. Mission Failed.